# How to limit the threads running in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, selenium, thread-safety

I have this code:

```
foreach (var s in linesTxt)
{
    if (!myList.Contains(s))
    {
        myList.Add(s);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            Processor(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Which gets every Details in a single .txt file, one data per line.

This is the Threading part :

```
public void Processor(string Sample)
{
    //Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    ThreadStart Thread1 = new ThreadStart(() => firstFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread2 = new ThreadStart(() => secondFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread3 = new ThreadStart(() => thirdFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread4 = new ThreadStart(() => fourthFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread5 = new ThreadStart(() => fifthFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread6 = new ThreadStart(() => sixthFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread7 = new ThreadStart(() => seventhFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread8 = new ThreadStart(() => eightFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread9 = new ThreadStart(() => ninthFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread10 = new ThreadStart(() => tenthFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread11 = new ThreadStart(() => eleventhFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread12 = new ThreadStart(() => twelveFunc(Sample));
    ThreadStart Thread13 = new ThreadStart(() => thirteenFunc(Sample));
    Thread[] mainThread = new Thread[13];
    mainThread[0] = new Thread(Thread1);
    mainThread[1] = new Thread(Thread2);
    mainThread[2] = new Thread(Thread3);
    mainThread[3] = new Thread(Thread4);
    mainThread[4] = new Thread(Thread5);
    mainThread[5] = new Thread(Thread6);
    mainThread[6] = new Thread(Thread7);
    mainThread[7] = new Thread(Thread8);
    mainThread[8] = new Thread(Thread9);
    mainThread[9] = new Thread(Thread10);
    mainThread[10] = new Thread(Thread11);
    mainThread[11] = new Thread(Thread12);
    mainThread[12] = new Thread(Thread13);
    foreach (Thread myThread in mainThread)
    {
        //ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(26, 26);
        //p.Refresh();
        //Console.WriteLine("Before start: {0}", p.Threads.Count);
        myThread.Start();
    }
}
```

The `firstFunc, secondFunc ....` contains the selenium c# code.

Note: I already tried using the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` but it is not successful.

For Example, If the txt file contains 20 data, then my pc will not respond, but if it only contains 5 or less then it works even though I experience some lags.

What I want is to able to process any number of data in txt file.

**Updated**

The firstFunc contains this:

```
                    var driverService1 = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    driverService1.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                    var driver1 = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService1);
                    driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://sample.com");
                    driver1.FindElement(By.Id("urlInput")).SendKeys(Domain);
                    driver1.FindElement(By.ClassName("convert-url")).Click();
                    var wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in']//p//input")));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    val1 = driver1.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in']//p//input")).GetAttribute("value");
                    if (Results.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        Results.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Results.Items.Add(DomainSearch + " => " + "http://sample.com => " + val1); }));
                    }
                    driver1.Quit();
                    driverService1.Dispose();
```

Comment: What are each of the `firstFunc`, `secondFunc`, etc, doing? Are they returning a value (given that they contain `Func` in the name) or are they just doing an action?

Comment: So you are returning stuff. Are all the funcs like this?

Comment: They're all the same

Comment: Due to lack of time I just tweaked it using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `Parallel` :

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;

Parallel.Invoke(options,
  () => firstFunc(Sample),
  () => secondFunc(Sample),
  () => thirdFunc(Sample),
  ...
);
```

Or `Task.Factory` :

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 1000);

Task[] tasks = new Task[3] {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => firstFunc(Sample)),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => secondFunc(Sample)),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => thirdFunc(Sample)),
    ...
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Is that all the code I needed to implement it using Parallel?

Comment: Yes, with Parallel or Task.Factory there's  no need to deal with the threads.

Comment: I think my only choice here is to use threads because it is very slow even I'm using only one data.